# How can I flatMap a custom-created class?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java (particularly Java-8 style), and I am trying to get a a List that contains coordinates that surround other coordinates. It's best to illustrate with an example.

I have defined a custom class that is a Coordinate, that looks like:

```
public class Coord {
    public final int row;
    public final int col;

    public Coord(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public List<Coord> surroundingCoordinates() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                // Up & down
                new Coord(row + 1, col), new Coord(row - 1, col),
                // Left and right
                new Coord(row, col + 1), new Coord(row, col - 1),
                // Diagonals
                new Coord(row - 1, col - 1), new Coord(row - 1, col + 1),
                new Coord(row + 1, col - 1), new Coord(row + 1, col + 1)
        );
    }

    public static List<Coord> surround(Coord c) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                // Up & down
                new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col), new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col),
                // Left and right
                new Coord(c.row, c.col + 1), new Coord(c.row, c.col - 1),
                // Diagonals
                new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col - 1), new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col + 1),
                new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col - 1), new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col + 1)
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to build a function (static method) that goes over a collection of Coordinates, and results in one flattened List that contains all surrounding coordinates. In other words, I want to map a function to a List of Coordinates, and then flatten the result to end up with a List of coordinates. My function looks like:

```
public static Stream<Coord> getSurroundingCoordinates(Coord[] coordinates) {
    // Turn the array of coordinates into a List
    List<Coord> coordsList = Arrays.asList(coordinates);
    // Trying to map and then flatten (fails)
    return coordsList.stream().flatMap(Coord::surroundingCoordinates);
}
```

I get greeted with the IDE compile error (at coord::surroundingCoordinates):

```
Required type: Function
Provided: <method reference>
```

So I tried to use a static method instead of a method, like:

```
public static Stream<Coord> getSurroundingCoordinates(Coord[] coordinates) {
    // Turn the array of coordinates into a List
    List<Coord> coordsList = Arrays.asList(coordinates);
    // Trying to map and then flatten (fails)
    return coordsList.stream().flatMap(c -> Coord.surround(c));
}
```

I get greeted with the IDE compile error at  c -> Coord.surround(c):

```
Required type: List<Coord>
Provided: Stream <Object>
```

The final result that I am after is one flat Collection of Coordinates

Comment: `flatMap` returns a `Stream`, not a `List` (as your method expects). Just add `.flatMap(...).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Hi @Eugene. I corrected my methods. I still get the same error. Where should I add the snippet? And do I need to collect?

Comment: _I get greeted with the error_ - are we supposed to guess where that happens?

Comment: @Eugene. I updated my question. Let me know if is still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's better even for performance reasons to make your surround method return Stream instead of List. Just do like this:

```
class Coord {

public static Stream<Coord> surround(Coord c) {
    return Stream.of(
            new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col), new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col),
            new Coord(c.row, c.col + 1), new Coord(c.row, c.col - 1),
            new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col - 1), new Coord(c.row - 1, c.col + 1),
            new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col - 1), new Coord(c.row + 1, c.col + 1)
    );
}

public static Stream<Coord> getSurroundingCoordinates(Coord[] coordinates) {
    List<Coord> coordsList = Arrays.asList(coordinates);
    return coordsList.stream().flatMap(Coord::surround);
}}
```

If you want to get list from stream later it's easier, than conversion list to stream on every iteration:

```
surround(c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You just got the syntax a bit wrong, I guess:

```
public static Stream<Coord> getSurroundingCoordinates(Coord[] coordinates) {
    return Arrays.stream(coordinates).flatMap(c -> c.surroundingCoordinates().stream());
}
```